Why is the URL Launcher doesnt work, am I doing it wrong?
I got this code from Chat GPT, and I already asking many times to Chat GPT why is it error, but it doesnt help at all, and then I tried using the URL Launcher logic from the internet, and it still doesnt work, so I comeback using the code from chat gpt. Anyway here is the code :
void _launchWhatsApp() async {
    final Uri url =
        Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com");
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
        await launchUrl(
        url,
        mode: LaunchMode
            .externalApplication, 
       );
     } else {
       throw 'Could not launch $url';
     }
  }

And I call it in here
floatingActionButton: DraggableFab(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _launchWhatsApp,
      tooltip: 'Compose Message',
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF1F2348),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0), 
      side: const BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white, 
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.headphones_rounded,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      )),

And YES I already do the pubspec and import it, and also already do the android/IOS permission for Internet.
Please Help me solve this

is there any error or something? or it's just not executed?

its executing, but it throw 'Could not launch $url' which mean it can't launch the url

canLaunchUrl resolves as false if you don't have permissions. You might want to show your "android/iOS permission for Internet" as it seems the error might be there. Also, you are opening youtube website in a function called _launchWhatsApp? Maybe you gave permissions for whatsapp:// but are trying to open https://?

Nevermind, I already solve it by adding this code below inside my AndroidManifest.xml file.












Thank you for your time

Just add this block of code inside AndroidManifest.xml inside quaries
<intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>

